# SWI-Prolog check if two elements in different lists are at the same position

Tags: prolog

I got an assignment where I need to write a predicate "same_position(L1,L2,E1,E2)" where L1 and L2 are lists, E1 is a element from L1 and E2 is a element from L2. the predicate is true when E1 and E2 are in the same positions in their lists.
I need to solve this problem using recursion

this is my solution to the problem:

```
same_position([L1|_],[L2|_],E1,E2) :- L1==E1,L2==E2.
same_position([_|L1],[_|L2],E1,E2) :- same_position(L1,L2,E1,E2).
```

this works, but not fully as expected, along with the assignment came a sample output where the below part is the problem. The expected output gives values for L before printing false where mine solution simply prints false. what am I doing wrong?

Expected output:

```
?- same_position(L, [a,a,c], 3, a).
L = [3|_G1667] ;
L = [_G1769, 3|_G1772] ;
false.
```

Mine output:

```
?- same_position(L,[a,a,c],3,a).
false.
```

Comment: Perhaps first define predicates that solve the problem for lists with *one* element, then for lists with *two* elements, and then aim to generalzie this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is:

```
same_position([L1|_],[L2|_],E1,E2) :- L1==E1, L2==E2.
same_position([_|L1],[_|L2],E1,E2) :- same_position(L1,L2,E1,E2).
```

The [**`(==)/2`** [swi-doc]](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3D)/2) predicate is defined as:

> **`@Term1 == @Term2`**
>
> `True` if `Term1` is equivalent to `Term2`. A **variable is only identical to a sharing variable**.

So that means that for a variable `X`, only `X == X` holds, not `X == Y` (unless `X = Y`), and `X == 3` always fails (unless `X` was already *grounded* to `3`).

Based on your sample output, you however do not want to check equality, you want to *unify*, which is what `(=)/2` does:

```
same_position([L1|_],[L2|_],E1,E2) :- L1 = E1, L2 = E2.
same_position([_|L1],[_|L2],E1,E2) :- same_position(L1,L2,E1,E2).
```

In Prolog however, we can also inify in the *head*, by using the *same* variable twice (or more) in the head:

```
same_position([L1|_],[L2|_], L1, L2).
same_position([_|L1],[_|L2],E1,E2) :- same_position(L1,L2,E1,E2).
```